# Change the color of circle in matplotlib

Tags: python, colors

I'm plotting a circle, but I want to change the color of the circle in this code. Can someone help me?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)
y = np.linspace(-1.0, 1.0, 100)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

F = X**2 + Y**2 - 1.0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contour(X,Y,F,[0])

ax.set_aspect(1)


plt.xlim(-1.25,1.25)
plt.ylim(-1.25,1.25)

plt.grid(linestyle='--')

plt.savefig("plot_circle_matplotlib_03.png", bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show()
```

I try put other the lines for instance `facecolor='auto'` and try to change the line
`plt.savefig("plot_circle_matplotlib_03.png", bbox_inches='tight')`

put
`plt.savefig("plot_circle_matplotlib_03.png", bbox_inches='tight', 'back')`
but actually I don't now what is the function of this line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you want from the question, but if you want to change the circle's color to for example green just do:

```py
ax.contour(X,Y,F,[0], colors=['green'])
```

If you want to change the color of the inner background:

```py
ax.set_facecolor('yellow')
```

Outer background:

```py
plt.savefig("plot_circle_matplotlib_03.png", bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='red')
```

Result:

[image]

Note that it doesn't exactly make sense to draw this as a contour plot (all the points on the circle have the same height 0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Only want to change the color of the circle, for instance for green, red or other in the code appear blue.

Comment: Alright, please consider accepting my answer if it helped you